# I have an error with jersey repository in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jersey, repository, pom.xml

when i add jersey repository :

```
<repository>
             <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.netSnapshotRepository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
```

to my pom.xml from here, :

```
https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-webapp, the id Line will have a red underlined error and giv this error : Malformed POM C:\Java\factor\pom.xml: expected START_TAG or END_TAG not TEXT (position: TEXT seen ...<repository>\r\n            \ua0\ua0\ua0), so my progect doesn't build .
```

this is my pom file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ir.iais</groupId>
<artifactId>factor</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>factor</name>
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:http://git.iais.co/scm/fac/factor.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:http://git.iais.co/scm/fac/factor.git</developerConnection>
    <url>scm:git:http://git.iais.co/scm/fac/factor.git</url>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <prime-db.version>1.3</prime-db.version>  
    <servlet-api.version>2.5</servlet-api.version>  
    <commons-codec.version>1.9</commons-codec.version>   
    <commons-validator.version>1.4.0</commons-validator.version>
    <poi-version>3.10.1</poi-version>
    <jetty-version>9.2.4.v20141103</jetty-version>
    <jersey-version>2.17</jersey-version>
    <orgjson-version>20140107</orgjson-version>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${poi-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${poi-version}</version>
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ir.iais</groupId>
        <artifactId>prime-db</artifactId>
        <version>${prime-db.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.76-beta</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/version.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/version.txt</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>                
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>            
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
     <repository>
             <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.netSnapshotRepository for Maven</name>                       <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

oh thanks , there is bad spaces in code because I copy it from the site . After i write it myself it's ok

Comment: you should mark your own answer as accepted ;) check http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer